# java custom annotation to use a class field

Tags: java, logging, annotations, refactoring

I'm in a situation where I need to log some events and there are too many of them. So I want to be able to do this:

```
class S{
  Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(S.class)

  // default logger annotation to print 
  // >> [info] 'method void foo(A) was invoked'
  @Log
  void foo(A x){
     /*...*/
  }

  // a specified comment to log
  // >> [info] 'message to log'
  @Log("message to log")
  void foo(A x){
     /*...*/
  }
}
```

Then I need a custom annotation for this. As you can see I need to be able to access a variable and get method name dynamically. Is that possible in Java?

Comment: It is possible, but why not writing `logger.info("a message to log")` at the beginning of the method?

Comment: As in the first example, i want to get method name , parameter types and all that included. Second one is only an alternative. And moreover I might need something more complicated then that, like defining a level of warning by simply writing @Log(Warning.HIGH) and such. And even different Log annotations to provide some more flexibility than just hard coding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about what exactly you are asking, but I can tell you this:

You can always look at the current stack trace if you want to see the name of the method that you're in: new Exception().getStackTrace(). Variable names are not in the Java bytecode unless you compile in debug mode.